# dual postfix setup for local and gmail

Tags: postfix

On my Ubuntu 14.04 desktop, I setup local mail using Postfix by following [this guide](http://www.cmsimike.com/blog/2011/10/30/setting-up-local-mail-delivery-on-ubuntu-with-postfix-and-mutt/) exactly.

Is it possible to retain the local messaging functionality while adding an external (gmail) account to send command line emails to the outside world?  If so, how?

Edit - Basically, I want cron messages to be local and the ability to fire off command line emails via Gmail.

Edit- current config:

```
$ postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_transport = error
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mydestination = HP-Pavilion-dv7.laptop, HP-Pavilion-dv7, localhost.localdomain, localhost
myhostname = HP-Pavilion-dv7
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
myorigin = /etc/mailname
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_transport = error
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
```

Comment: Ya it is possible,Please add your current `postconf -n` output and some examples for the above requirement.

Comment: @clement done :)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to authenticate using your gmail address username and password and send out mails through gmail's SMTP server from this postfix server?

Comment: yes, that is what I mean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to configure `Sender-Dependent SASL authentication` in Postfix. Please add the following lines to your `main.cf`

```
#/etc/postfix/main.cf    
#...
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes 
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd 
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587 
smtp_tls_security_level = may 
smtp_sasl_security_options =
#...
```

and create `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` with the following content.

```
user1@gmail.com  user1@gmail.com:password1
user2@gmail.com  user2@gmail.com:password2
```

Do a `postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and reload postfix.

Ref: [Postfix docs](http://www.postfix.org/SASL_README.html#client_sasl_sender)

All your `local` mails will be delivered as before. If you send a mail to `someone@yahoo.com` from `user1@gmail.com` using the following command

```
echo "Hi Everyone"|mail -s "Test email" -r "user1@gmail.com" someone@yahoo.com
```

then your postfix server will authenticate using `user1@gmail.com`'s password configured in `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd`. Hope that helps.